# How do I replace a placeholder text with an Image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a string `"Hello {world}"` which I need to replace with `"Hello "`. The placeholder's position is not fixed at the end. And I may have more than a single placeholder.

I am using SwiftUI and tried to make this work with

```
Text("Hello {world}".replacingOccurrences(of: "{world}", with: "\(Image(systemName: "globe"))"))
```

but soon found that this doesn't work and presented with this `Hello Image(provider: SwiftUI.ImageProviderBox<SwiftUI.Image.(unknown context at $1ba606db0).NamedImageProvider>)`

Since this worked

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("Hello \(Image(systemName: "globe"))"))
```

I assumed I needed to pass a `LocalizedStringKey` into the `Text` I tried again with

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey("Hello {world}".replacingOccurrences(of: "{world}", with: "\(Image(systemName: "globe"))")))
Text(LocalizedStringKey("Hello" + "\(Image(systemName: "globe"))")) //this doesn't work either
```

but presented with a similar issue `SwiftUI.Text.Storage.anyTextStorage(SwiftUI.(unknown context at $1ba668448).LocalizedTextStorage`

I looked at the API for `LocalizedStringKey` and `LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation` but could not find a solution this problem. Is there a way to make replacement of placeholder string work?

Comment: I suggest you read again 
the Swift basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html
and do the tutorial relating to SwiftUI at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/. Without understanding the difference between a `String` and a `Image(...)` you will struggle.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Hmm, I've did that already, can you please tell me which section I need to pay attention to?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I understand the difference, however Swift now supports String interpolation that we could use to add images to text without using a AttributedString, right? If you run on the playground `Text(LocalizedStringKey("Hello \(Image(systemName: "globe"))"))` you'd get `Hello ` on the preview. My question is how can I do that with a placeholder text and replacing that with a Image

Comment: ha, I think I understand your question now. How about using this: `var world = "globe"` and `Text(LocalizedStringKey("Hello \(Image(systemName: "\(world)"))"))`, then you can change the `world` string as desired.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Interesting, but I think my problem is the other way around. My input string is a variable, that is `"Hello {world}"` and taht comes from an API. The image for `{world}` and other placeholders is stored in a local dictionary that I populate. Can you think of a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came to this question via answering [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73743661/852828) and it piqued my interest. As I say in my answer there, the secret sauce is that `LocalizedStringKey`, *when initialised with an interpolated string literal*, is capable of building in references to SwiftUI `Image` types which can be rendered in `Text`.

Because you're not using an interpolated string literal, you can either build things up by multiple `Texts`, as in the other answers here, or do something smart with `LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation`. The advantage of this approach is that you can also use the image-holding text in any other view that uses `LocalizedStringKey` (which is, well, pretty much any of them that display text).

This extension on `LocalizedStringKey` will manually build an interpolated string:

```swift
extension LocalizedStringKey {

    private static let imageMap: [String: String] = [
        "world": "globe",
        "moon": "moon"
    ]

    init(imageText: String) {
        var components = [Any]()
        var length = 0
        let scanner = Scanner(string: imageText)
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil
        while scanner.isAtEnd == false {
            let up = scanner.scanUpToString("{")
            let start = scanner.scanString("{")
            let name = scanner.scanUpToString("}")
            let end = scanner.scanString("}")
            if let up = up {
                components.append(up)
                length += up.count
            }
            if let name = name {
                if start != nil, end != nil, let imageName = Self.imageMap[name] {
                    components.append(Image(systemName: imageName))
                    length += 1
                } else {
                    components.append(name)
                }
            }
        }

        var interp = LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation(literalCapacity: length, interpolationCount: components.count)
        for component in components {
            if let string = component as? String {
                interp.appendInterpolation(string)
            }
            if let image = component as? Image {
                interp.appendInterpolation(image)
            }
        }

        self.init(stringInterpolation: interp)
    }
}
```

You may want to cache these values if they are coming from an API, I haven't checked the performance of this code in a rendering loop.

You add an extension on `Text`, or any other view:

```swift
extension Text {
    init(imageText: String) {
        self.init(LocalizedStringKey(imageText: imageText))
    }
}
```

So you can do this:

```swift
Text(imageText: "Hello {world}! or {moon} or {unmapped}")
```

Which gives you:

[image: Text view with interpolated images]

Comment: This might be the best answer yet. However, there seems to be a bug with SwiftUI that interpolates `"{world}{moon}"` into `"1"`  Edit: Weird, Even `Text("\(Image(systemName: "globe"))\(Image(systemName: "moon"))")` produces `"1"`

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! Putting a space between them works, it must be some issue with the implementation of `LocalizedString.StringInterpolation`

Comment: Useful note: The method `appendInterpolation` takes an AttributedString as a parameter as well. So, if one want a blue italicised text in place of `{unmapped}` instead of just plain text, you could do that or if you'd want style to be configurable, set up another static dictionary like `imageMap` that defines `AttributeContainer` against a style key, say `"style1__"` and append the resulting `AttributedString` to the components. So that `"Hello {world}! or {moon} or {style1__unmapped}"` could produce a blue `unmapped` text

Comment: Great solution! Thanks very much! Any thoughts on how to combine this with markdown support? eg `Text(imageText: "**Hello** {world}")` doesn't work, though `Text("**Hello** \(Image(systemName: "globe"))")` does.

Answer (score 6):

After looking at @bewithyou's answer, I got the idea that I need to split this into multiple substrings and recombine the texts individually. This is the best solution I could come up with:

```
public extension String {
    
    func componentsKeepingSeparator(separatedBy separator: Self) -> Array<String> {
        
        self.components(separatedBy: separator)
            .flatMap { [$0, separator] }
            .dropLast()
            .filter { $0 != "" }
    }
}
```

And on playground, if I were to run this, it works perfectly.

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(

    "Hello {world}!"
        .componentsKeepingSeparator(separatedBy: "{world}")
        .reduce(Text("")) { text, str in
            if str == "{world}" { return text + Text("\(Image(systemName: "globe"))") }
            return text + Text(str)
        }
)
```

I'm sure there is a more optimal solution, but this will do for now.

**EDIT:**

Since I needed support for multiple placeholders, I've added some more extensions that does the job more comprehensively.

```
func componentsKeepingSeparators(separatedBy separators: [Self]) -> [String] {
    
    var finalResult = [self]
    separators.forEach { separator in
        
        finalResult = finalResult.flatMap { strElement in
            
            strElement.componentsKeepingSeparator(separatedBy: separator)
        }
    }
    return finalResult
}
```

and on the playground

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    "Hello {world}{world}{world}! {wave}"
        .componentsKeepingSeparators(separatedBy: ["{world}", "{wave}"])
        .reduce(Text("")) { text, str in
            if str == "{world}" { return text + Text("\(Image(systemName: "globe"))") }
            if str == "{wave}" { return text + Text("\(Image(systemName: "hand.wave"))") }
            return text + Text(str)
        }
)
```

This extension has a double loop and might not be very efficient, so  again, if someone can think of a better solution, please do post.

Answer (score 2):

For your question the key here is not `LocalizedStringKey` but the key here is `\()` methods means string interpolation.

> According to [Swift document](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#:%7E:text=String%20interpolation%20is%20a%20way,line%20and%20multiline%20string%20literals.), string interpolation is a way to construct a new String value from a mix of constants, variables, literals, and expressions by including their values inside a string literal. You can use string interpolation in both single-line and multiline string literals.

In here it combines two things which is `Text("hello")` and `Image(systemName: "globe")` into a new String. Your code is wrong because of you append the string of value.

Without `LocalizedStringKey`, `Text` will appear as same as your `Hello !`.

```swift
Text("Hello \(Image(systemName: "globe"))!")
```

Or you can use as combination for easier understanding

```swift
Text("hello") + Text(Image(systemName: "globe")) + Text("!")
```

And for you question about mapping value you can make a dictionary for mapping image or name image do that

```swift
var dict : [String:String] = ["world" : "globe"]

// Add default name image value if key is nil
Text("Hello \(Image(systemName: dict["world", default:"globe"]))!")
Text("hello") + Text(Image(systemName: dict["world", default: "globe"])) + Text("!")
```

```swift
var dict : [String:Image] = ["world" : Image(systemName: "globe")]

// Add default image value if key is nil
Text("hello\(dict["world", default: Image(systemName: "globe")])!")
Text("hello") + Text(dict["world", default: Image(systemName: "globe")]) + Text("!")
```

All of them works the same an print out `Hello !`

Comment: I can follow most of the answer, however an you please add a example on how to convert `"Hello {world}!"`, the whole string into the Text `Hello !`. I'm not quite sure how I could achieve this..

Comment: Dear @Aswath, you just need simply add ``Text("!")`` or ``Text("Hello \(Image(systemName: dict["world", default:"globe"]))!")`` then all set. I've just updated above

Comment: Ok, all your solutions work, but their input is hardcoded, that is `"Hello {world}!"`. What I need is a algorithm that takes a variable input and returns me a Text that would have worked as if it were hardcoded.

Comment: Dear @Aswath, as far as your solution is worked

Comment: Anyhow, thanks to your answer, I got a hint to separate the text and recombine them

Answer (score 1):

Using @Aswath's answer, here's a custom container:

```
struct CText: View {
    var text: String
    var placeholders: [String: String]
    var imagePlaceholders: [String: Image]
    public init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.placeholders = [:]
        self.imagePlaceholders = [:]
    }
    private init(_ text: String, placeholders: [String: String], imagePlaceholders: [String: Image]) {
        self.text = text
        self.placeholders = placeholders
        self.imagePlaceholders = imagePlaceholders
    }
    private var array: [String] {
        let strings = Array(placeholders.keys)
        let images = Array(imagePlaceholders.keys)
        return strings + images
    }
    var body: Text {
        text
            .componentsKeepingSeparators(separatedBy: array)
            .reduce(Text("")) { text, str in
                if let place = placeholders[str] {
                    return text + Text(place)
                }else if let place = imagePlaceholders[str] {
                    return text + Text("\(place)")
                } else {
                    return text + Text(str)
                }
            }
    }
    func replacing(_ holder: String, with replacement: String) -> CText {
        var oldPlaceholders = placeholders
        oldPlaceholders[holder] = replacement
        return CText(text, placeholders: placeholders, imagePlaceholders: imagePlaceholders)
    }
    func replacing(_ holder: String, with replacement: Image) -> CText {
        var oldPlaceholders = imagePlaceholders
        oldPlaceholders[holder] = replacement
        return CText(text, placeholders: placeholders, imagePlaceholders: oldPlaceholders)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        CText("Hello {world}")
            .replacing("{world}", with: Image(systemName: "globe"))
    }
}
```

Edit: If you need to access `Text` instead of `View`, add `.body` at the end:

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        CText("Hello {world}")
            .replacing("{world}", with: Image(systemName: "globe"))
            .body
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, also uses the declarative syntax as a bonus

Answer (score 1):

This is a small improvement to @jrturton's answer tweaked to my needs. Perhaps this might benefit others. However, this is very different to my original answer, and so it made sense to me to add this as a new answer. The `deletingPrefix` is from [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-remove-a-prefix-from-a-string)

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

extension String {

    func deletingPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> String {
        guard self.hasPrefix(prefix) else { return self }
        return String(self.dropFirst(prefix.count))
    }
}

extension LocalizedStringKey {
    
    @available(iOS 15, *)
    init(imageText: String, replacementClosure: (String) -> Any) {
        
        var components = [Any]()
        var length = 0
        let scanner = Scanner(string: imageText)
        scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil
        
        while scanner.isAtEnd == false {
            let up = scanner.scanUpToString("{")
            let start = scanner.scanString("{")
            let name = scanner.scanUpToString("}")
            let end = scanner.scanString("}")
            if let up = up {
                components.append(up)
                length += up.count
            }
            if let name = name {
                if start == nil || end == nil { self.init(stringLiteral: imageText) }
                let replacement = replacementClosure(name)
                
                switch replacement {
                    
                case let image as Image:
                    components.append(image)
                case let attributedString as AttributedString:
                    components.append(attributedString)
                case let plainString as String:
                    components.append(plainString)
                default:
                    print("No action.")
                }
            }
        }

        var interp = LocalizedStringKey.StringInterpolation(literalCapacity: length, interpolationCount: components.count)
        for component in components {
            if let string = component as? String {
                interp.appendInterpolation(string)
            }
            if let attrString = component as? AttributedString {
                interp.appendInterpolation(attrString)
            }
            if let image = component as? Image {
                interp.appendInterpolation(image)
            }
        }

        self.init(stringInterpolation: interp)
    }
}


extension Text {
    
    init(imageText: String) {
        self.init(LocalizedStringKey(imageText: imageText, replacementClosure: { string in
            
            switch string {
                
            case "world":
                return Image(systemName: "globe")
            case "moon":
                return Image(systemName: "moon")
            case let stylisedString where stylisedString.hasPrefix("style1__"):
                return AttributedString(stylisedString.deletingPrefix("style1__"), attributes: AttributeContainer().foregroundColor(.blue))
                
            default: return string
            }
        }))
    }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(Text(imageText: "Hello {world}! or {moon} or {style1__unmapped}")
)
```