# How do pass a string with an Image in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do you pass a string that contains an Image in SwiftUI?

This works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(Image(systemName: "apple.logo")) Sign in with Apple")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

This does not work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var text = "\(Image(systemName: "apple.logo")) Sign in with Apple"
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

If I try to pass the string as a stored variable SwiftUI doesn't show the image.

[image]

Comment: You could use a `(NS)AttributedString`

Comment: *string that contains an Image* is a contradiction in terms. `String` and `Image` are not related to each other (the Unicode Emojis are a special case). Use `Label` as suggested by Joakim.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not sure everyone understands that you can pass an Image inside a string for Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Label` instead of a `Text` component

```
Label("Sign in with Apple", systemImage: "apple.logo")
```

or if you want to use a string property then you must declare it as a `LocalizedStringKey` so that the right `init` will be called

```
var text:LocalizedStringKey = "\(Image(systemName: "apple.logo")) Sign in with Apple"
```

(without this it looks like what is used is the `description` property from `CustomStringConvertible`)

Have a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743661/why-does-the-behaviour-of-localizedstringkey-depend-on-whether-i-pass-a-string-i) for some more in depth information about `LocalizedStringKey`

Comment: I have a more complicated use case with multiple images in the string. I'm not understanding why it works passed as a string and not as a computed property.

Comment: I updated my answer. If the string is passed directly to Text it works.

Comment: See my updated answer for another way to do this.